# Publishing referee reports I have written - Yes or No and How?

Tags: peer-review, repository

I remember reading somewhere about someone who started publishing referee reports they had written online, along with sending them to the journal (or after). Unfortunately I do not remember where I saw this and can't seem to find it now.

I see strong arguments for this practice.

1. A lot of time and effort is spent on report writing, so why not list them.
2. Transparency for its own sake.
3. Transparency for the sake of increasing quality.

Obviously there are issues:

1. Copy right or other legal issues with journals prohibiting the publication of reports [has to be taken up with the editor]
2. If the paper itself is not published, publishing the report might be harmful to the authors [one could wait until the final version of the paper is published]

**My question**: Is this already common practice somewhere and do repositories exist where one can upload reports? Are there other strong counterarguments I am missing?

Comment: You need to be careful before doing this. I remember reading (no time to look for source right now unfortunately) that some publishers explicitly prohibit reviewers from publishing their reviews. Also, in some fields at least, reviewers are expected to pretend they they're not reviewers after reviewing.

Comment: The ones I wrote. I hope my edits made the question clearer

Comment: It is often explicit (and even more often implicit) that the manuscript sent to you for review is "privileged information" which you are not allowed to disclose to the public.  I take that to include disclosing that such a manuscript exists.

Comment: Sure, but I am not talking about publishing the manuscript, only me review of it

Comment: @sheß Publishing a review derived from "privileged information" is also a problem. (Consider the reviewing process as taking place under an NDA, hence, you cannot reveal the manuscript nor what you derive from the manuscript.)

Comment: @Allure From a legal standpoint, the journals have no claim over reviews. I wrote them, I did not sign an NDA or a contract or anything, I am free to do what I want with them. Do not let the journals bully you out of *more* of your work than they already do.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you sure? Because lots of journals have written policies on the responsibilities of the peer reviewer, and accepting the reviewer invitation can be interpreted as tacitly agreeing to those policies.

Comment: @Allure I am not a lawyer (and especially not one in every country of the world), but this seems equivalent to a [browse-wrap license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browse_wrap), which would be invalid because the license terms are not presented in a sufficiently conspicuous way to the reviewer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I can imagine why universities make their students take mandatory academic integrity courses, so students can't claim to be unaware of it. Imagine if one day a reviewer submits an intentionally fraudulent review, then claims that they weren't aware of the journal's policy that the reviewer give honest critical feedback. As a result journals start requiring all reviewers sign a form saying they agree to abide by the policy. Won't that be a tragedy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are repositories. You could consider registering with Publons (see https://publons.com/home/). You simply forward the 'thank you for your review' email and upload the review and Publons keeps track of what journals you have reviewed for etc. Many of the major publishers are now automatically linking to Publons so you can simply press a button when you complete the review and you don't even need to do the upload.

In theory, Publons keeps track of whether the journal allows the review to be made public, but I have found that to be unreliable for one of the journals I regularly provide reviews to so you should take care. But Publons does other useful things like track whether a paper is eventually published, provide a summary of your review activity etc.

Comment: The question is about publishing the *text* of the peer review, which Publons does not, as far as I know.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes it does. For example, see the FAQ at https://publons.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/12000012207-what-review-information-is-displayed-review-display-preferences- about how to control access to the uploaded reiew.

Answer (score 8):

Take care with this. Since you write them, the words are yours unless the journal has required that you yield all rights to them or otherwise restricts your actions.

However, you should consider whether it is ethical to break the blind or double blind nature of review. There are reasons for that, though some are a bit esoteric.

If you need to say negative things about someone's paper and they take it personally, then you could find yourself in the middle of an academic war and those other people with an interest in an author's work might join the fray.

You also need to be sure that whatever you need to quote in a review is properly cited as in any other work. This makes publishing a double-blind review impossible, of course.

Some things might need to be confidential for various reasons, including patentable work. Some things need to be reserved until the paper is published, I think.

However, maybe the biggest issue is as follows. Often enough, by the time a paper is edited and re-edited, it no longer bears a lot of similarity to the version that you reviewed. In some fields this is a bigger problem than others, of course, but don't discount it. This will, potentially, reflect badly on yourself if you say things about a paper that aren't true about the published version.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than publishing private reviews, wait until the submitted manuscript is published and then publish a critique. You can base your critique on your private review (albeit, this may compromise your anonymity), but you must update it to consider the published version, rather than the submitted manuscript.

Comment: +1. That makes sense. The critique need not even refer to the review or mention that it was done. Then anonymity isn't compromised. Anyone can critique an article.

Comment: @Buffy Those privy to the review can perhaps unveil the reviewer's identity.